# Table View Cells start shaking when trying to swipe to delete current cell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Here's my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("editingStyle")
        if editingStyle == .delete {

           //Doing my task  

        }
}
```

Every time I swipe left, the other cells start shaking and creates a really bad user experience. 
I have tried some hacks like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kCellReuseCardIdentifier) as? MyCustomTableViewCell {

            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 16, height: 125)
            cell.frame = frame
            cell.contentView.frame = frame
//            Cells get squished when editing mode is enabled. To prevent that from happening , we create a dummy cell
            let dummyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kDummyCellIdentifier) as! DummySpaceTableViewCell
            dummyCell.addSubview(cell.contentView)
            dummyCell.clipsToBounds = true

            return dummyCell
}
```

The funny thing is that this [hack](http://https:stackoverflow.com/questions/9966956/swipe-to-delete-on-a-uitableviewcell-cell-gets-squished)  works in iOS 11 beta. In iOS 10 this causes the cell shaking problem. Do note that my tableView has **n** sections and each section has **1** row. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used MGSwipeTableCell to prevent from above issue.
You can find the code & examples from below link.
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    experienceCell * experienceCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"experienceCell"];
     MGSwipeButton *DeleteButton=[MGSwipeButton buttonWithTitle:@"" icon:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete_white"] backgroundColor:THEME_COLOR padding:15];

                DeleteButton.titleLabel.font=ROBOTO_REGULAR_FONT16;

                experienceCell.rightSwipeSettings.transition=MGSwipeTransitionStatic;
                experienceCell.rightExpansion.buttonIndex=0;
                experienceCell.rightExpansion.fillOnTrigger=true;
                experienceCell.rightButtons=@[DeleteButton];
                experienceCell.delegate = self;
                experience = true;
     return experienceCell;
    }
    -(BOOL) swipeTableCell:(MGSwipeTableCell*) cell tappedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(MGSwipeDirection)direction fromExpansion:(BOOL) fromExpansion
 {
if(direction == MGSwipeDirectionRightToLeft && index == 0)
{
}

return YES;
}
```